# Change font-family of open website

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Is it possible to change the current font-family of a web site to a different one programmatically?
For example, the Google's search box (HTML input element where you type your search query)..
I want to change it's default font-family, which i believed is Arial or Sans Serif, to Windings. (or any font that is not readable by a human's eye)
Guys, any ideas here? btw, the prefered browser is internet explorer.

Comment: You realize you can't just edit someone else's webpage, right? That's like writing in a book and expecting everyone else who owns that book to be able to see your addition.

Comment: In firefox, you can edit css styles by right clicking -> Inspect Element. You will see on the right pane the css of that open page which can be modify and immediately applied. (I tried this on google, i change it's search box's font-family to papyrus)
Knowing this, i think that maybe some programming language or script can do the task, since, firefox is an application build using a programming language, i think..

Comment: The question is obscure, but from your comment about CSS injection below, it seems that you are displaying someone else’s page in a frame or inline frame and would like to modify its style. That would in normal cases constitute copyright infringement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do it in your own website not someone else's (like google).
In you CSS you can do it like

```
*{
font-family: Calibri;
}
```

The * will set font for all your website.
If you want to do it in someone else's website I don't think its possible.

Comment: Uhm..actually i need to do it on other's website. Is it possible?
btw, i have read that there's a way, by using CSS injection. But i think, this is not the safest way.

Comment: Aha! in IE, you can modify the css styles of the open web pages. IE allows you to browse a css file and apply it to all open web pages in IE. thanks everyone!